# Is cgminer used for both bitcoin and litecoin GPU mining?

Tags: cgminer, ubuntu, linux, mining-software

I'm trying to figure out which software to download for my Ubuntu 12.04 box to start some litecoin mining.  Via google search, I keep coming up with cgminer for both bitcoin and litecoin mining.

How does that work, is the same software cgminer used for both bitcoin and litecoin mining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cgminer can be used to mine both LTC and BTC.  When executed to mine Litecoin one would need to add the command line switch --scrypt  It is also worth noting that the last version to support GPU mining and scrypt is version 3.7.2  Versions after that have all GPU mining capability removed.

Comment: All versions after 3.7.2 have GPU mining capability removed? As in anything newer than 3.7.2 has had GPU mining removed? Why is that?

Comment: going forward they will only support asic mining but I suspect the open source community will fork the project and potentially continue supporting gpus